# What is difference between ObjectResult and JsonResult

Tags: json, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

There are two classes in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` namespace:

`ObjectResult` and `JsonResult`.

Both convert the returned object in the JSON format.

What is difference between them and what is the purpose to use them?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

`JsonResult` is an `IActionResult` which formats the given object as JSON

`ObjectResult` is an `IActionResult` that has content negotiation built in.

Inside its `ExecuteResultAsync`, responsible for writing to the response stream, the framework will walk through the available formatters and select a relevant one.

The logic for choosing a formatter is similar to that in ASP.NET Web API, and based on the following order of precedence:

- Accept header
- Content-Type header
- selection based on type match

**OkObjectResult Class**

> An `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ObjectResult` that when executed performs
> content negotiation, formats the entity body, and will produce a
> `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.StatusCodes.Status200OK` response if
> negotiation and formatting succeed.

References:

- [Migrate from ASP.NET MVC to ASP.NET Core MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/mvc)
- [Asp.Net Documentation: JsonResult Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.jsonresult)
- [Asp.Net Documentation: ObjectResult Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.objectresult)
- [Asp.Net Documentation: OkObjectResult Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.okobjectresult)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So ObjectResult is more universal class and there is no any reasons to use JsonResult?

Comment: If you want to just return json data then use `JsonResult`. If you want the api to be more flexible and allow for different formats to be return then `ObjectResult` will allow for content negotiation.

Comment: Why not use ObjectResult to return json too (in this case it will be in the same style)? What is advantages of JsonResult in this case?

Comment: I guess it is a matter of preference. JsonResult allows you to restrict content type without much work.