# IActionResult vs ObjectResult vs JsonResult in ASP.NET Core API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

What's the best option to use in a Web API that will return both `HTTP status codes` and `JSON` results?

I've always used `IActionResult` but it was always a Web App with a Web API. This time it's **only Web API**.

I have the following simple method that's giving me an error that reads:

> Cannot implicitly convert type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.OkObjectResult
>   to System.Threading.Tasks.Task Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult

```
[HttpGet]
public Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
   return Ok();
}
```

Comment: You can use `Ok` method to return data with 200 OK

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38788559/what-is-difference-between-objectresult-and-jsonresult) should help with part of the question. On top of that, `IActionResult` will support both status codes and JSON objects.

Comment: Return the object that best suits the needs of the request. As for the action's method definition, define it with IActionResult to allow the flexibility of using an abstraction as apposed to tightly coupled concretions

Comment: Just updated the original post to see the error I'm getting without even any logic. Why would I get that error?

Comment: Because the method isn't async.

Comment: No, that's not it. SO is not showing the rest of it because of brackets. I just removed them.

Comment: It's a conversion issue from OkObjectResult to IActionResult. Not sure where OkObjectResult is coming from.

Comment: @Sam no. The method/action body is not async so you have to return a task, otherwise remove the task altogether and just return `IActionResult`.

Comment: Yes! I see what you mean now. Sorry a bit slow.

Comment: @Sam here is a good article you should read http://hamidmosalla.com/2017/03/29/asp-net-core-action-results-explained/

Comment: For unit tests checking for StatusCode, I found it was convenient to cast to the shared IStatusCodeActionResult , when the controller returns either StatusCodeResult or ObjectResult

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Return the object that best suits the needs of the request. As for the action's method definition, define it with `IActionResult` to allow the flexibility of using an abstraction as apposed to tightly coupled concretions.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get() {
   return Ok();
}
```

The above action would return 200 OK response when called.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get() {
   var model = SomeMethod();
   return Ok(model);
}
```

The above would return 200 OK response with content. The difference being that it allows content negotiation because it was not specifically restricted to JSON.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get() {
   var model = SomeMethod();
   return Json(model);
}
```

The above will only return Json content type.

A very good article to read on the subject

[Asp.Net Core Action Results Explained](http://hamidmosalla.com/2017/03/29/asp-net-core-action-results-explained/)