# Proxy call for remote json to avoid CORS issue

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, cors, asp.net-core-webapi

I develop an angular app that needs to consume json data from a remote server. Due to CORS issue, the app cannot directly fetch data from that server. My solution is to develop a "proxy" web api to read and return that json to my app. Currently, this is the way I'm doing:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> MyJson()
{
    const string jsonUrl = "url-of-remote-json";
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var result = await client.GetAsync(jsonUrl))
        {
            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return new ObjectResult(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()));
            }
        }
    }

    return new ObjectResult(new { });
}
```

However, I believe this is far from being considered an efficient way because I have to read the json as string, then convert it to object using JsonConvert package to feed the web api method. Therefore, the performance is not really good.

I wonder if there is any easier/efficient/more simple way to do this task?

Comment: What is the need to convert the json response from the server to an object?. If there is no specific need you can send the response as you receive it.

Comment: Can you show sample code to do that? Thanks.

Comment: One option is to use JsonResult. you can refer to the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38788559/what-is-difference-between-objectresult-and-jsonresult?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @pradeep-kumar: JsonResult requires an object (to be converted to json format) instead of a string. My code reads the remote json as a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pass throu the response from the remote server. Look at the edited example.

```
public async Task MyJson()//void if not async
{
    string jsonUrl = "url-to-json";
    HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] bytes = await client.DownloadDataTaskAsync(jsonUrl);
            //write to response stream aka Response.Body
            await HttpContext.Response.Body.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        catch (Exception e)//404 or anything
        {
            HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 400;//BadRequest
        }
        await HttpContext.Response.Body.FlushAsync();
        HttpContext.Response.Body.Close();
    }
}
```

Works as expected.

Comment: Doesn't work. Return "System.Byte[]" instead of the json.

Comment: The example comes from working code. Make sure that there is no `return` in the function.

Comment: I copied your entire code and change the link to remote json only.

Comment: Thanks. This works. For those who want to use HttpClient instead of WebClient, see my modified code below.

Answer (score 2):

This is a modified version of @Alex's code, using HttpClient instead of WebClient:

```
public async Task MyJson()//void if not async
{
    string jsonUrl = "url-to-json";
    HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] bytes = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(jsonUrl);
            //write to response stream aka Response.Body
            await HttpContext.Response.Body.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        catch (Exception e)//404 or anything
        {
            HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 400;//BadRequest
        }
        await HttpContext.Response.Body.FlushAsync();
        HttpContext.Response.Body.Close();
    }
}
```

This is my actual code:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> MyJson()
    {
        const string jsonUrl = "url-to-json";
        HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] bytes = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(jsonUrl);
                //write to response stream aka Response.Body
                await HttpContext.Response.Body.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                await HttpContext.Response.Body.FlushAsync();
                HttpContext.Response.Body.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return new BadRequestResult();
            }
        }

        return new BadRequestResult();
    }
```

Comment: The main idea is **not to return** from the function. Your version returns `BadRequestResult` always.

Comment: @Alex: I see your point and it's great. However, my version returns the json when there is no exception raised and return BadRequestResult only when there is exception.

Comment: Note that `HttpClient` is not meant to be used like this; it is meant to be reused. See [You're Using HttpClient Wrong](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2019/09/using-http.aspx)